# Помогите восстановить пользователя

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено

Был здесь такой пользователь Nikolja с почтой mihl сoбaка meta точка ua.
Сейчас при попытке войти и ввести адрес этой почты, форум пишет "Нет учётной записи для данной почты".

Если подробнее. 
Во-первых, прошу прощения, что пишу не в разделе Мета. Но там нужны баллы репутации, чтобы создать тему.

Тему "Как начать пользоваться Русский язык Stack Exchange имея учётную запись на форуме Русский язык?" смотрели, запрос на почту послали. Пришло следующее.

<<

Был получен запрос на восстановление учетной записи Русский язык для
mihl coбaка meta.ua. Если вы не запрашивали восстановление, просто
проигнорируйте это сообщение. Ваша учётная запись в безопасности.

Вы можете войти на Русский язык(https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/login) c помощью следующих
 учетных данных:
mihlcoбaка meta.ua
(нажмите здесь для настройки пароля)*

<<

Причём надпись "нажмите здесь для настройки пароля" - это просто текст. Нажимать некуда.

Если можно, помогите пользователю Nikolja. Всё-таки он не один год на этом форуме.

Comment: Я тоже долго ходил кругами и тыкал кнопки. Вышел непонятным способом, но точно через почту, которая приходила при нажатии ссылки "забыли пароль?". Из письма был выход на работающую схему смены пароля - его пришлось менять, причём потребовали символы и цифры приделать. Потом (возможно, из следующего письма через ссылку "войти") получилось попасть на страницу, где сверху уже высвечиваются персональные цифирки. Ник при этом не показывается, но всё работает (посты идут от моего ника). Как я понял, нельзя заново регистрироваться - возможны новые проблемы.

Comment: А почему бы вам не попробовать зайти через социальную сеть, если вы зарегистрированы в какой-нибудь из них.

Comment: В соц. сетях не зарегистрирован.

Comment: Я так понимаю, из коммента Alex_ander, что надо выслать пользователю на почту сообщение, с РАБОТАЮЩЕЙ ссылкой на что-то. На смену пароля что ли. Пока на указанную почту пришло 2 одинаковых письма, по которым непонятно куда идти. Их текст выше. Может быть местный админ обратит на это внимание и вышлет ещё одно сообщение для активации?

Comment: Отправил вам письмо для восстановления доступа еще раз. Пожалуйста, попробуйте перейти по одной из предоставленных ссылок. Если не получится, пишите, будем искать решение вместе.

Comment: Спасибо, получил. Письмо точно такое же, как и предыдущие 2 (см. их текст выше).

Ссылку для перехода лично я пока нахожу там только одну:

https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/login

Может быть я чего-то не замечаю?

Comment: Если переходить по этой ссылке, то там есть вход через StackExchange. Я пробую заходить через него. Или надо как-то по-другому? Ну и как я уже в вопросе сразу написал, форум опять пишет **"Нет учётной записи для данной почты"**. Может новый пароль куда-то высылается? В общем или я где-то путаюсь или где-то ошибка.

Comment: Мне подозрительно и непонятно, что этому сайту не нравится не ПАРОЛЬ (тогда можно делать запрос, что забыл пароль), похоже, что этот сайт не воспринимает саму ПОЧТУ, ну именно ЭТОТ e-mail.

Answer (score 4):

Я зашёл в настройки своей электронной почты.

Поставил галочку в настройках "Показывать html-сообщения".
Ещё нашёл в настройках так называемый "белый список". Адреса, занесённые
туда, не отправляются в папку "Спам". Внёс туда адрес "Stack Exchange"
.

Теперь надпись *"Нажмите здесь для настройки пароля"* пришла в виде **работающей** ссылки. Ну вот, я нажал на неё, ввёл новый пароль и вошёл на обновлённый сайт.

**Большое спасибо администратору за помощь!** Это его советы по электронной почте помогли мне разобраться с этим вопросом.

Comment: Я вас поздравляю! Рад видеть!

Comment: :-) Спасибо! Приятно.